# Override a generic base class property with a constructed return type

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine, generics

I want to use Generic type definitions in the Unity Editor and cannot (yet) update to Unity 2020.1 which natively supports this. The workaround is to define a non-generic class that extends the generic class.
However, when I try to override a base class property, with a defined class which is basically a named version of the generic property, the compiler reports both types to be incompatible. Since this description is quite ... generic ... here is some code to illustrate my issue:

```cs
class Property<T> { }

class BaseClass<T>
{
    public virtual Property<T> Property { protected get; set; }
}

class StringProperty : Property<string> { }

class SubClass : BaseClass<string>
{
    public override StringProperty Property { protected get; set; }
}
```

```
SubClass.Property': type must be 'Property<string>' to match overridden member 'BaseClass<string>.Property
```

SubClass.Property is basically `Property<string>` but I don't know how to communicate this to the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HimBromBeere explains perfectly why your code won't compile, but there is a workaround, albeit slightly more verbose.

Have your base accept the type of `Property<T>` rather than just `T`:

```
class BaseClass<TProperty, T> where TProperty : Property<T>
{
    public virtual TProperty Property { protected get; set; }
}
```

Now you can declare your subclass like this:

```
class SubClass : BaseClass<StringProperty, string> { }
```

If you have several subclasses that require `Property<string>`, you could introduce another level into your hierarchy:

```
class SubClassString<TProperty> : BaseClass<TProperty, string> where TProperty : Property<string>
{ }
```

Now your subclass can be declared more concisely:

```
class SubClass : SubClassString<StringProperty> { }
```

Comment: Interesting solution! Is it `T Property { protected get; set; }` or `TProperty  Property { protected get; set; }` in `BaseClass`?

Comment: @aleneum Yes it should be `TProperty`.

Comment: While @HimBromBeere's answer is technically the most appropriate explanation why what I wan't cannot be done, this answer proposes the solution for my underlying problem: by passing `StringProperty` and converting `Property` into a variable such as `public TProperty Property;` it appears serializable for Unity and thus becomes available (as in editable) in the Editor.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that while every `StringProperty` is a `Property<string>`, not every `Property<string>` is a `StringProperty`. Sounds weird? So here we go.

Imagine a client of your class has this:

```
BaseClass<string> b = new SubClass();
```

Now one would assume that we can do this:

```
b.Property = new MyProperty();
```

where `MyProperty` also derives from `Property<string>`. However this contradicts your expectation that instances of `SubClass` have a `StringProperty`, not a `MyProperty`.

That has nothing to do with generics. In short you cannot change the signature of a member by overriding it. Both the base-class- and the derived-class-member have to have the exact same signature, including the return-type.

Comment: It basically boils down to this, I guess. While StringProperty could be treated as a `Property<string>`, not every `Property<String>` can be treated as a `StringProperty`. I was hoping c# has some 'declare' magic (which is obviously not inheritance) where I can say "this is basically this but with a name".

Answer (score 4):

Covariant return types are not supported. I believe it is added with C# 9.

It means that you can not change the return type of the overridden method. Even if the overridden method returns a derived type.

Something like this is not valid:

```
class Animal
{

}

class Cat : Animal
{

}

abstract class AnimalFactory
{
    public abstract Animal CreateAnimal();
}

class CatFactory : AnimalFactory
{
    public override Cat CreateAnimal(); // Syntax error
}
```

Although we are returning an `Animal` (a `Cat` is an `Animal`), it will give a compiler error.

Comment: This is not simply related to return types; `Property` has a setter, so can never be (safely) covariant.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Visual Studio gives me the error: `Cannot change return type when overriding property.`

Comment: I get _'SubClass.Property': type must be 'Property<string>' to match overridden member 'BaseClass<string>.Property'_. The return type is only one issue.